# How can I match some parts of an expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, rule

Suppose I have an expression like `Abs[x+I y]+Sin[Abs [c+ I (d+e)]]`,

and I want to replace all expressions in the form of `Abs[a1 + I a2]` to `Sqrt[a1^2+a2^2]`.

How should I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr = Abs[x + I y] + Sin[Abs[c + I (d + e)]];

expr /. Abs[a_ + I*b_] -> Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]

(*  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + Sin[Sqrt[c^2 + (d + e)^2]]  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

Use `ComplexExpand`

```
expr = Abs[x + I y] + Sin[Abs[c + I (d + e)]];

expr // ComplexExpand
```

> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + Sin[Sqrt[c^2 + (d + e)^2]]

Comment: It makes assumptions about symbols that are not necessarily in this form too. But as quick solution it is probably fine.

Comment: @Kuba - the second argument to ComplexExpand is used to designate any variables in the expression that are complex.