# Absolute value of a complex function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I do not know why this method does not work for calculating the absolute value (or norm of `(E^((-3 I t)/4) + 3 E^((5 I t)/4)) (E^((-3 I t)/4) - E^((5 I t)/4))`);

```
f[t_] := (E^((-3 I t)/4) + 3 E^((5 I t)/4)) (E^((-3 I t)/4) - E^((5 I t)/4));
Refine[Abs@f[t], Assumptions -> {t > 0, t ∈ Integers}]
```

Comment: Pardon me if I'm misunderstanding what you are doing. Aren't you trying to find the absolute value of a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several Q&A which show the use of [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) for this sort of task, such as [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44934/4999), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46926/4999), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80031/4999) and so on, but I guess the different expressions in each case distinguish the questions from each other.

Perhaps one of these two forms would be acceptable:

```
Simplify@ComplexExpand[Abs@f[t]]
Simplify[%, t > 0]
(*
  2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[5 + 3 Cos[2 t]] Sqrt[Sin[t]^2]
  2 Abs[Sin[t]] Sqrt[10 + 6 Cos[2 t]]
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
f[t_] := (E^((-3 I t)/4) + 3 E^((5 I t)/4)) (E^((-3 I t)/4) - E^((5 I t)/4))
```

[image]

```
Sqrt @ FullSimplify @ Total @ ((ComplexExpand @ ReIm @ f[t])^2)
```

[image]

---

Thanks to [Jack LaVigne](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/10917/jack-lavigne) I'd like to emphasize that the outer pair of round brackets (i.e., those enclosing the `...^2`) are necessary: it appears that without them the squaring `^2` is done last, leading to an incorrect result.

Comment: Regarding the outer brackets, perhaps conventional function notation `Total[x^2]` would be the more natural choice here.